# Spring batch how to run a job in loop until it meets a condition?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

```
<job id="firstJob" restartable="true"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="FirstStep">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="read" writer="write"
                commit-interval="1" />
        </tasklet>
    </step>
</job>



<job id="second_job" restartable="false"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="second_step" ">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="reader_again" writer="writera_gain"
                commit-interval="500" />
        </tasklet>      
</job>
```

I have two jobs here (3 in my actualcode). I want to run  the first job to check for some value inthe database and only execute once it finds that value. For this I want it to keep looping until it can find the data and then continue. How can I do this through Spring Batch xml? Is there a better way to do this?

Also, I can't change the structure i.e make two jobs into two steps due to the size of the codebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes control flow of one job can be directed to another job with "Externalizing Flow Definitions". You can simply use While(condition) in first job and then specify flow to reach second job

One way could be to simply declare the flow as a reference to other:

```
<job id="job">
   <flow id="job1.flow1" parent="flow1" next="step3"/>
   <step id="step3" parent="s3"/>
</job>

<flow id="flow1">
   <step id="step1" parent="s1" next="step2"/>
   <step id="step2" parent="s2"/>
</flow>
```

Details on https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html#external-flows